# QueryOptions ignored when getting calendar events in MSGraph Dot Net

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm trying to get the user's calendar events for today. So I added some query parameters but they're getting ignored and the graph client returns the user's events as if I didn't supply any parameters (`startatetime`):

```
var options = new QueryOption[]
{
    new QueryOption("startdatetime", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")),
    new QueryOption("enddatetime", DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1).ToString("o")),
};
var events = await graphServiceClient
    .Me
    .Calendar
    .Events
    .Request(options)
    .GetAsync();
```

I tested it in the graph explorer and it works fine. But in the sdk, it returns calendar events that started before today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is the equivalent of calling:

```
`/events?startdatetime={dateTime}&enddatetime={dateTime}`.
```

That is a valid endpoint, but you're passing invalid query params. What you're looking for is [calendarView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs):

```
`/calendarView?startdatetime={dateTime}&enddatetime={dateTime}`
```

Using the SDK, this would look like this:

```
var options = new QueryOption[]
{
    new QueryOption("startDateTime", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")),
    new QueryOption("endDateTime", DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1).ToString("o")),
};

var events = await graphServiceClient
    .Me
    .CalendarView
    .Request(options)
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know where I got `events` from. Thanks!

Comment: I think that the answer is right but not exactly its explanation. If I'm not wrong the real fact is that *events* endpoint  doesnt support startDateTime nor endDateTime query options. I guess that that is because events endpoint deals with general events, that would not have an specific dateTime if they are repeated events, while calendarView manages event instances, where they can be more easily filtered by date.

Comment: It's also remarkable that, not being supported or working parameters, the API doesn't return an error but returns the query unfiltered. It would be desirable to return an error or at least, have this behavior better documented.

Comment: This is how Graph works. If you provide invalid query params, Graph will simply ignore them.